# offset latitude slightly if not unique

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, maps

I have a bunch of events with their location being pulled from the db and I am doing the following:

```
List<Place> placeList = new List<Place>();
foreach (var item in eventsList)
{
    bool coordinateExist= placeList.Where(x => x.latitude == item.Latitude && x.longitude == item.Longitude).Count()>0;
    Place place;
    if (coordinateExist)
        place = new Place() { title = item.Title, latitude = item.Latitude+0.0001, longitude = item.Longitude};
    else
        place = new Place() { title = item.Title, latitude = item.Latitude, longitude = item.Longitude};

    placeList.Add(place);
}
```

I have a slight issue though. If two locations have the exact same latitude and longitude I want to offset the latitude by the slightest amount (equiv to a few meters maybe?), and then add it to placeList. Hence I will have a list full of unique coordinates.

how can i achieve this nicely? The above works but not nice IMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you choose to do this will depend on how many items you expect to put into the list and how fast you want your list population to be.

If the list is very small, you can check the list for identical places and then update your latitude, check again, etc.  That is:

```
foreach (var item in eventsList)
{
    var latitude = item.Latitude;
    var longitude = item.Longitude;
    while (placeList.Any((p) => p.latitude == latitude && p.longitude == longitude))
    {
        // adjust item latitude
    }
    Place place = new Place() { title=item.Title, latitude = latitude, longitude = longitude };
    placeList.Add(place);
}
```

As you can imagine, that gets hugely expensive if the number of events is large, because you have to search the entire list at least once for every item that you add.

If that becomes too expensive, you can maintain a `HashSet` of latitude/longitude pairs, and check it as you're adding items.  Come to think of it, you could just build the thing as a `HashSet` and then convert it to a list:

```
class Place: IEquatable<Place>
{
    public int longitude { get; set; }
    public int latitude { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }

    public Place (int long, int lat, string ttl)
    {
        // initialization here
    }

    public bool Equals(Place other)
    {
        return (this.longitude == other.longitude) && (this.latitude == other.latitude);
    }
}

...
HashSet<Place> Places = new HashSet<Place>();

foreach (var item in eventsList)
{
    var place = new Place(item.Title, item.Longitude, item.Latitude);
    while (!Places.Add(place))
    {
        // Adjust place.Latitude
    }
}

// Finally, convert it to a list.
List<Place> Placelist = Places.ToList();
```

That still has potential pathological behavior if you have a lot of events with the same latitude/longitude.  You can minimize those effects by adding a small random amount when you adjust the latitude.  That is, rather than just adding 2 meters or whatever, add a random amount between 1 and 10 meters, for example.  Or, you might want to randomly move the longitude, too.

If you were to do as @anon suggested:  build the list with the duplicates and then remove them later, you'd end up doing something very similar.  That is, you'd probably build a `HashSet` of visited locations and test against it while removing the dupes.

Comment: @raklos: I think it is now.  I forgot the `return`.

Comment: CompareTo is not being invoked. I added a break point in that method. and it doesnt go here for some reason?

Comment: @raklos: I goofed.  The thing needs to implement `IEquatable`, or override `Equals`.  Anyway, I think the modified sample should work now.  That's what I get for not testing my example, huh?

Answer (score 1):

I've done something like this before.  The tricky part is that you might have more than 2 places that have the same location.  They best solution is to do multiple passes over your list (AFTER getting them from the DB).  In each pass, you maintain a new list of latitude/longitude pairs that you've "seen" before, and, in your loop, if a place occupies a location that you HAVE seen before, you move it.  When you finally have a pass where you have not moved a place, you are done.